# ImportError: No module named '_tkinter'

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ubuntu-16.04

Python Version: `3.5.2`

Installation Type: Native package installation

Additional Packages installed: `python3-tk tk-dev`

After installing the packages as mentioned in other answers I am still getting the error mentioned `ImportError: No module named '_tkinter'`

Although is present in `/usr/local/python3.5/tkinter`.

What may be the issue?

Comment: it is a server, there is no tkinter installed

Comment: If it is Ubuntu Server, then why to try to install a GUI library (tkinter or whatever) ?

Comment: some application dependency, for that I need to install

Comment: Ok, what if you try: `sudo apt-get install python3.5-tk`?

Comment: ya, I installed it, `python3.5-tk` and `python3-tk` both are same packages